# Can I use openCV4Android to process the video recorded by Android camera?

Tags: android, opencv

Is there any methods that I can capture the frame from Android camera and pass it to openCV function, finally return the processed images to encode the video? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

OpenCV4Android does not yet support video decoding and encoding. For this you'd have to use FFmpeg with Android. Build FFmpeg, decode video using AVutils in native code and process each frame using OpenCV. I recently did this. I used FFmpeg to decode frames and used OpenCV to convert RGBA frames to Gray frames and show it on the screen.

[FFmpeg with OpenCV on Android](http://www.jayrambhia.com/blog/ffmpeg-opencv-android/) this would be helpful. This works in a bit different way. You can use OpenCV's `cvCameraBridgeView` function to get the frames from the camera, or use CameraPreview and processFrame callback method, where you call OpenCV function (in native code or in java) to porcess the frame and use FFmpeg to encode the video (in native code).